# Greatest Common Divisor Challenge(Euclidean Algorithm)

Tags: java, algorithm

everyone I've tried to solve the Greatest Common Divisor and it seem running  well but i think its long code and I'm new to java and i need some advice what can i improve with the code.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(GCD(888,54));
    }
    public static int GCD(int a, int b){
        int r = a % b;
        if(r != 0){
        int rem = b % r;
        if (rem > 10){
                int aRem = r % rem;
                if (aRem < 10){
                    return aRem;
                }else {
                    int bRem = rem % aRem;
                    return bRem;
                }
            }else {
                return rem;
            }
        }else {
            return r;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The euclidian algorithm can be implemented either in a recursive or in an iterative way. Yours is neither the one, nor the other. In other words: you will either need a loop or you'll need to call `GCD` from within `GCD`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/, which is the site to use when [you have a **working piece of code** from your project and are looking for **open-ended feedback**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: thanks for the advice @csabinho ill try to edit my code..

Comment: @RickSanMateo the accepted answer is inefficient. For `a == b` it takes `a` loops instead of just one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do using a for loop.

Sample code.

```
public static int GCD(int a, int b){
  int gcd = 1;
  for(int i = 1; i <= a && i <= b; i++){
      if(a%i==0 && b%i==0)
         gcd = i;
  }
  return gcd;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using recursion as well. 
Try using this code in your method.

```
public static int GCD(int a, int b){
        if(b == 0){
            return a;
        }
        return GCD(b, a%b);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The iterative way of implementing GCD in Java is the following:

```
public static int GCD(int a, int b) {
    while (b != 0) {
        int temp = a;
        a = b;
        b = temp%b;
    }
    return a;
}
```

This is an alternative to the recursive solution from Peter. The advantage is, that is won't use `Stack` space that much. It has the same time complexity but better memory complexity (`O(1)`) and will work for all valid data not risking the `StackOverflowError`.